# Android Integer.parseInt negative number

Tags: android, textview, android-edittext

I'm new to development so sorry if my question is very simple.
I'm developing an app for D&D. When the user inserts a number in the first edittext i use onTextChanged of edittext so I setText to the second edittex the result.

My problem only occurs if the checkbox is checked. If the checkbox is not checked, it works fine but if the checkbox is checked the app will make a sum (proficiencybonus + mod). It works but only for positive numbers. When the app sets a velue of f.e. `-5` the app crashes. The data is all saved in the sharedpreferences.

```
checkBox_strength.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
            if(checkBox_strength.isChecked()) {

                float result_num;
                int num1, num2;
                int f= 0;

                DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.##########");

                num1 = Integer.parseInt(proficiencybonus.getText().toString());

                if (strength_mod.getText().toString().length() > 0) {
                    num2 = Integer.parseInt(strength_mod.getText().toString());

                } else {
                    num2=f;

                }

                result_num = num1 + num2;
                strength_save.setText(" = " + df.format(result_num));


                editor.putBoolean("checkBox_strength", true);
                editor.apply();
            }else{
                editor.putBoolean("checkBox_strength", false);
                editor.apply();
            }
        }
    });
```

Have tried something else but I can't go find a solution

```
float result_num;
                int num1, num2;
                int f= 0;

                DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.##########");

                num1 = Integer.parseInt(proficiencybonus.getText().toString());

                if (strength_mod.getText().toString().length() > 0) {
                    num2 = Integer.parseInt(strength_mod.getText().toString());

                } else {
                    num2=f;

                }

                result_num = num1 + Math.abs(num2);
                strength_save.setText(" = " + df.format(result_num));
```

This is my error of the crash, it crashes "num2 = Integer.parseInt(strength_mod.getText().toString());"

```
2020-05-03 17:09:24.440 10318-10318/jekanapplication.charactersheet5e E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: jekanapplication.charactersheet5e, PID: 10318
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "−1"
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:608)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:643)
    at jekanapplication.charactersheet5e.MainActivity$51.onCheckedChanged(MainActivity.java:1394)
    at android.widget.CompoundButton.setChecked(CompoundButton.java:172)
    at android.widget.CompoundButton.toggle(CompoundButton.java:128)
    at android.widget.CompoundButton.performClick(CompoundButton.java:133)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24931)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:101)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:166)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7529)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:245)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:921)
```

[image]

Comment: Could you please add your error logs?

Comment: @DaanSeuntjens update now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem is how set the text in the second edittext , is use onTextchange of the first edittext, I set the text edittext.settext"-2" I have changed in edittext.settext"R.String.two_" so when the i get the text I have no proble when I get the string.

Answer (score 0):

In the XML define this attribute: `android:inputType="numberSigned"`

Comment: Change it to numbersigned @LuigiJe

Comment: tried but nothing also tried "android:inputType="numberDecimal|numberSigned""

Comment: Yes always the same "For input string: "−1""

Comment: Check other strings other than number, what about them?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213038/discussion-between-luigi-je-and-mohammadmoeingolchin).

Comment: Please check in which line you have error, Integer.parseInt(edittext.text.toString()) works correctly for me. @LuigiJe